# PHP: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, rest, api

I have the script below and was wondering why I was getting the error:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
```

The base64 encoded value is in the form `username:password` and is correct. The API documentation gave the example as:

```
Authorization: Basic
QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

For example, if the user agent uses Aladdin as the username and open sesame as the password, then the field is formed as above in the HTTP header

```
  <?php
    $postData = array(
        'primaryContact' => array('id' => 1),
        'subject' => 'Something not working'
    );

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=\r\nContent-Type: application/json",
            'content' => json_encode($postData)
        )
    ));

    // Send the request
    $response = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/', FALSE, $context);

    // Check for errors
    if($response === FALSE){
        die('Error');
    }

    // Decode the response
    $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    // Print the date from the response
    echo $responseData;
    ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: With what are you trying to connect? Is it supposed to stay on the localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and your code works. i think its the server. atleast check the server username and password again (your base64 code is correct)

I tested on: iis 7.5 the website has basic auth setup (http 401 Challenge) 
(on iis that means that i can use my windows server credentials)

add the $http_response_headers to your error line to get more information.

```
// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
    var_dump($http_response_header);
    die('Error');
}
```

Comment: Adding \r\n to the end as a previous comment suggested fixed it for some reason